# could not find function "generateFunctionalANOVAData"

Tags: mlr

use the mlr 2.12.1 to do the interaction analysis

just run the example code on the http://mlr-org.github.io/exploring-learner-predictions-with-partial-dependence/

but return the error as follows:

```
lrn.regr = makeLearner("regr.ksvm")

fit.regr = train(lrn.regr, bh.task)

fa = generateFunctionalANOVAData(fit.regr, bh.task, "lstat", depth = 1, fun = median)
```

with error

```
Error in generateFunctionalANOVAData(fit.regr, bh.task, "lstat", depth = 1,  : could not find function "generateFunctionalANOVAData"
```

mlr version:

```
[1] ‘2.12.1’
```

Comment: I opened an issue https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/2294 , apparently It was removed for some reason. In the meantime you could try using https://github.com/zmjones/fanova or install mlr version 2.11 from CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

hey sorry i am the author of fanova and the module of mlr that uses it. unfortunately i don't have it working on reasonably sized data, so i removed it from mlr. you can of course try out fanova directly, but it isn't going to be included in mlr until i improve it.

Comment: I'am a little confused now, which paper the fanova refer to？

Comment: I'm a little confused. Which paper should I refer to ? this one 
 ? https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/106186007X237892#.WyHAWVOFPUI     And the code https://github.com/zmjones/fanova could work fine on the larger dataset?

Comment: yes, it implements the simple method in that paper. the full method he describes isn't in the package. no the package doesn't currently work on larger datasets, that is why i removed it from mlr